# Mean of the deviations from the mean

Tags: standard-deviation, variance

I ve been struggling to understand the below problem.If I could get help with this problem, it would be greatly appreciated. 
Consider the data y, y+a, y+2a,….,y+na and the deviations of these observations from their mean. The mean of these deviations is,

```
A] {n(n+1)a}/(2n+1)
B] {n(n-1)a}/(2n+1)
C] (n+1)a/2n
D] None of these
```

So mean of the deviations of each observation from their mean? Im a little lost.

Comment: The mean of the *signed* deviations is always zero--this can be considered the defining property of the mean, in fact. Did you want the mean of the *unsigned* deviations (i.e. the absolute values of the deviations)?

Comment: thx for the prompt response @Ian ... Im not too sure.. but i guess i need the mean of the unsigned deviations...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a direct approach. The mean is

$$
\frac{1}{n+1} \sum_{k=0}^n y + ka
= y + \frac{a}{n+1} \sum_{k=0}^n k
= y + \frac{an(n+1)}{2(n+1)} = y + \frac{an}{2}
$$

The mean of deviations is
$$
\frac{1}{n+1} \sum_{k=0}^n |y + ka - y - an/2|
= \frac{a}{n+1} \sum_{k=0}^n |k - n/2|
$$
can you finish this?

Comment: y do we have n+1 in the denominator... isnt it supposed to be n?

Comment: @ronn you have $n+1$ values, count them: $y+0a, y+1a, \ldots, y+na$...

Comment: aargh... my bad :) thx for pointing it out :)